# JavaScript: Why is the innerHeight not updating?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch the new `innerHeight` when resizing my window. (I'm using `innerHeight` to specify height properties for DOM elements).

I'm finding in practice that the value of `innerHeight` is set when the page loads and does not update during resizing.

```
var onresize = function(e) {
   innerHeight = e.target.innerHeight;
   console.log('Inner height = ' + innerHeight);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
```

Could someone suggest what I should be telling my `onresize` variable to do instead? (And I'd be very grateful if anyone could spare the time to explain why this isn't working -- this is my first time playing around with resizing and `innerHeight`.)

Thanks!

EDIT: To add, I'm using Chrome and the console isn't reporting any problems.

Comment: do you mean `window.innerHeight` ?

Comment: your code works(tried on chrome)... i am not sure what your problem is...

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also what is the console reporting, if anything?

Comment: You're getting outer-WIDTH and inner-height. So if you change the width, only 1 will change, and if you change the height only 1 will change. Maybe it was a typo?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat, sorry you're right that was a typo. I've simplified it now so it's just showing the innerHeight, which doesn't seem to change as I change the browser height.

Comment: Is it working fine now?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on Chrome and I.E ( Dont have Mozilla on my computer), depending on your browser there could be some issues however namely

> From Firefox 4 to 24 this property was buggy

See more here [innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)